# Include text file in Report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Is it possible to include a plain text file to print in the Title band of a jasper report?The text file may reside in a local or remote folder with a dynamic file name.The filename shall be accessed in a field on the data source.

Comment: Do you want to include the entire file, or a string in report that load according to your requirement ?

Comment: entire file always.I have searched most of the forums relating to jasper and ireports but failed to find anything of this sort. i mean i can always get the text to a db field and make it print from there..but that will simply be a waste of resources.So exploring other alternatives....thanks.

Comment: Why not a parameter that load text content from file ?

Comment: even if i create a parameter type InputStream how would i use it in the expression for a text field. I have tried getContents, but it gives me a NoSuchMethodException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wound suggest you simply create a `String` report parameter, then you can just load content of text file before you export the report.

Here is a simple example:

```
JRExporter exporter = ...
...
...
exporter.setParameter("TITLE_TEXT", loadTitleTextFromFile());
exporter.exportReport();
```

where `loadTitleTextFromFile()` is the method that read file content and return as a string.

Comment: yes this is better than the db field read. But still , if jasper has some plugin or so which can read files and show internally, then that would have been great. i mean if end user has to edit these texts often then they got to be outside the jrxml for sure. and then passing the full text in db or as parameter is an option but i would always have chosen the other way, like the image widget, get the text file in the report in a pretty standard way ,dont u think so...or is it just me...?

Comment: You can always make `loadTitleTextFromFile()` read from the file that user can edit.